# Facebook - Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted

Tags: javascript, facebook

This is the code failed :

```
FB.ui({
     method: 'share',
     href: 'http://localhost:53530/RecipeDetails',
     name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
     link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
     picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
     caption: 'Reference Documentation',
     description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
     }, 
      function (response) { }
     );
```

With this code, I've the following error :

```
API Error Code: 100
API Error Description: Invalid parameter
Error Message: picture URL is not properly formatted
```

I don't understand why.

I tried also to change the method name 'share' to 'feed' but nothing changes.

Can you help me ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is I guess because the picture size has to meet certain specifications as mentioned [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2):

"The URL of a picture attached to this post. The picture must be at least 200px by 200px. See our documentation on [sharing best practices](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices#images) for more information on sizes."